# Excel Function Macro: Creating a drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a function that turns the cell into a dropdown list with values in it.

So far from what I read online, it only shows how to do it in `sub` form but I want to try to use it in the cell so it automatically populates it. So far I got this.

```
function test(val as Range)
    if val = 1 then
        set test = Range(name_of_defined_list)
    elseif val = 2 then
        test = "no list"
    end if
end function
```

And in the cell it would be written and dragged down to the cells below

```
=test(C2)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a function for this. Use a Sub Procedure (there is a reason you didn't find a way to do it with a function in your research)

Comment: You're comparing a range to an integer on your code. Besides, I think you can't turn a cell to a `droplist` with a function. You have to do it with a macro.

Comment: to elaborate on what @Pspl said, if `val` is a range larger than 1 cell, this will produce an error. If `val` is just one cell and contains an error (from formula) or is non-numeric (text) this will also produce an error

Comment: @urdearboy Ah, I need to do it in a Sub Procedure and then add it to my function. That makes sense. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

So I store the Procedure in my Function and I just use ActiveCell and it will know the cell it is currently in?

Answer (score 1):

Answer your first row question: I want to create a function that turns the cell into a dropdown list with values in it.

if you want this one then you can try this code:

```
Sub test()
'drop down list
Dim MyList(5) As String ' create array with definite size and value
MyList(0) = 1 ' assign value
MyList(1) = 2
MyList(2) = 3
MyList(3) = 4
MyList(4) = 5
MyList(5) = 6

'put in C2 array MyList
    With Range("C2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
    End With
    End Sub
```

or you can use un array with size dinamically and get items from cells

```
Sub test()
'drop down list example with 5 items into list
Dim MyList() As String
Dim i, myDim As Integer

myDim = 5 ' number of items that you can get from a cell
ReDim MyList(myDim)

'get items from cells. example A1-B1-C1-D1-E1
For i = 0 To myDim
    MyList(i) = Cells(1, i + 1) ' assign value into MyList
Next i

'cell A10 is mi drop down list
With Range("A10").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
End With
End Sub
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Would I be able to use this Sub and add it into my Function to use in every cell?

Comment: yes try the first...copy and paste in your vba module and keep me update...i tried and works. Try only my code to understand if works well for you. After we try to put in oyur function...

Comment: I added the Procedure into my function so I could add it like this in the cell: `=testFunc()` and in the Procedure I did `ActiveCell.Validation.....` but it doesn't work. Does the Procedure need to be on it's own?

Comment: Sorry, try in this way first. Use only my code and use f8 to execute the code step by step and after click on C2 cell(if your are using the first block of  code).

Comment: Yeah, the Procedure works fine by itself when executed but I was wondering more on it executing automatically when someone fills in a value in a cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182891/discussion-between-ferdinando-and-efoc).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to work around this type of requirement, but it might not meet your needs...

**Step 1**.  Create a function to be called when a user clicks on the in-cell validation list drop down. This example checks the value to the left of the cell and only if it's "Yes" does it return a range to be used for the list.

```
Function Lister()
    Dim rv As Range
    If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "Range" Then
        If Application.Caller.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Yes" Then
            Set rv = Sheet1.Range("A1:A5")
        End If
    End If
    Set Lister = rv
End Function
```

**Step 2**.  You can't reference this function directly from the validation list setup, so you need to use a workbook name to "route" the validation call to the function:

[image]

**Step 3**.  Create your in-cell drop-down, referencing the name you just created (which in turn links to the VBA function).  Now you'll get a list when the cell to the left has "Yes", but no list otherwise.  Or you could instead use the same approach to return two different lists, depending on the content in other cells.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after researching from all the answers I was provided, I found this link,
https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html

I was able to write a Change event Sub so that when the user adds a value to a cell and switches out of the cell, the sub runs and creates the dropdown list.